# Async Code Splitting NPM module issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Earlier I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672369/async-code-splitting-webpack-unexpected-token)

I have now setup a local package in my main app `package.json`:

```
"contact-page": "file:local_modules/contact-page"
```

I have setup the `package.json`main and scripts sections for the contact module like so:

```
"main": "dist/main.js",
"scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel index.js --out-file ./dist/main.js",
}
```

This makes sure the last line in `dist/main` is an `exports.default = ContactPage;`

So in my dynamic import in the main app, it has:

```
getComponent() {
    import('contact-page').then(ContactPage => {
        console.log(ContactPage.default);
    });
}
```

I just get `undefined` in the console log.

What kind of shape does my module have to be in for webpack to load it. I first tried with webpack building this module but to no avail...

Comment: have you tried "System.import('contact-page')". I can't keep up with the spec. Is webpack building multiple bundle files? Do you see a AJAX call in the console?

Comment: `System.import` has been dropped in favour for `import()`. I don't see an AJAX call which is concerning me - or another bundle file either.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to fix this.... not sure how.

But, I added a `tools/build.js` file that contains:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

const exec = (command, extraEnv) =>
    execSync(command, {
        stdio: 'inherit',
        env: Object.assign({}, process.env, extraEnv)
    });

console.log('Building CommonJS modules ...');

exec('babel modules/index.js --out-file dist/main.js', {
    BABEL_ENV: 'cjs'
});

console.log('\nBuilding main.js ...');

exec('webpack modules/index.js umd/main.js', {
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
});
```

Borrowed from react router.

Then just ran `node tools/build.js` and it created these two files. I then removed the `node_modules/contact-page` in order to do another `npm install`. And it just worked..... Oh I also changed my webpack config to:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    output: {
        library: 'ContactPage',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },

    externals: {
        react: {
            root: 'React',
            commonjs2: 'react',
            commonjs: 'react',
            amd: 'react'
        }
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
        })
    ]
};
```

Again, borrowed from react router